# Java converting integer to ASCII character A-F implicitly

Tags: java, char, int, ascii, implicit-conversion

How do I convert an integer to its **ASCII** equivalent implicitly, without using any conversion classes and without using explicit casting?

The issue faced is I am trying to convert the integer `12` to the letter `C` and append it to an existing String. My attempt is below:

```
s += 12 +'A'-10;
```

All this gets me is the output 67, which is the decimal equivalent of ASCII character 'C', but I need the letter C to be the output, not 67.

***Is there a way to do this without using multiple if-else-if statements and also not using what was mentioned above?***

Comment: The outpur depends on how to print actually, how do you print it?

Comment: Why not just `String.format("%X", 12)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the expression on the RHS:

```
12 + 'A' - 10
```

is of type `int`, since the `char` is automatically widened to an `int`; so the `+=` operator will concatenate the integer value to the string.

Two options (amongst others):

1. Cast to a `char`:

   ```
   s += (char) (12 + 'A' - 10);
   ```
2. Use `String.format`:

   ```
   s += String.format("%X", 12);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your problem.

```
    char s = 12 + 'A' - 10;
    System.out.println("s = '" + s + "'");
```

prints `s = 'C'`.

Comment: The problem is that `12 + 'A' - 10` is of type `int`, so `s += <that>` will append the integer value, not the char.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Did you try `s += (char) (...)`?

Comment: Yes, see my answer. The point is that sure, it works if you assign (or cast) it to a `char`, but OP isn't doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this:

```
char s = 'A' + 12 - 10;
```

will give the *character* `'C'`